# RcppArmadillo + bigmemory crashes Windows RStudio (but no other GUI + OS.type)

Tags: rstudio, rcpp, r-bigmemory

I'm working on an R package, [`bigKRLS`](https://github.com/rdrr1990/bigKRLS). [`bigKRLS`](https://github.com/rdrr1990/bigKRLS) works on Windows RGui but encounters a fatal error on Windows RStudio. Some details...

Windows RGui works but Windows RStudio encounters a fatal error; confirmed on four different machines using R 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.3; RTools 3.3 and 3.4 following the [best practices recommended by the Coatless Professor](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp/install-rtools-for-rcpp/); RStudio 1.0.136; Windows 7 and 8. Presently, [`bigKRLS`](https://github.com/rdrr1990/bigKRLS) works on RStudio for Mac OS X Yosemite and Ubuntu 14.04 without issue.

[`bigKRLS`](https://github.com/rdrr1990/bigKRLS) depends on [`bigmemory`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory), [`Rcpp`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp), [`RcppArmadillo`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo), and [`snow`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=snow) (but the problem pre-dates the recent addition of [`snow`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=snow), which can be disabled for testing purposes by setting `bigKRLS(..., Ncores = 1)`).

```
devtools::install_github('rdrr1990/bigKRLS')
library(bigKRLS)
vignette("bigKRLS_basics")

set.seed(2017)
X <- matrix(runif(60), ncol=3)
y <- X %*% 3:1 + rnorm(20)
out <- bigKRLS(y, X)
summary(out)
```

The code above yields model estimates started with R2 = 0.663 (we've of course estimated lots more complicated models on other platforms).

Windows RStudio loads `library(bigKRLS)` without warning; `bigKRLS()` outputs that it's cleaned the data successfully. Among other things, that means **y** and **X** are now `big.matrix objects`. Then the first "real" step: `bigKRLS()` calls `bGaussKernel()`, which is where the session aborts after two minutes or so. But there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with `bGaussKernel()`. `bGaussKernel()` runs just fine if called from the command line in under a second. In fact, if you initialize each variable that `bigKRLS()` requires, you can run all of its code in Windows RStudio.

[image: Windows Rstudio crash screenshot]

Currently, the [package detects when Windows RStudio is being used and safely exits the function](https://github.com/rdrr1990/bigKRLS/blob/338698e47c38bf18609390fb3d534dc18273cba8/R/bigKRLS.R#L39-L41), directing users instead to RGui. Any suggestions as to a better a workaround would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the problem on Windows is not related to the compiler. If you managed to install RTools correctly, then everything is going well for using *RGUI*. Instead, the problem that you are having seems to be with RStudio's use of Boost for their application that accidentally polluted calls to the `boost` namespace provided by the [`BH`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) package in the `rsession` process. RStudio, more so @kevinushey, recently addressed this issue by creating a custom build of Boost for RStudio that lives within `rstudio_boost`. The details and solution of this error can be found in more depth at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/1061.

Long story short, if this is indeed the case, simply check if the RStudio version is `>=1.1.129` will suffice. To do so, you will first need to get an [RStudio daily version](https://dailies.rstudio.com/). With this in hand, we can reference the solution that @DirkEddelbuettel derived for his fabulous [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package that was running into this issue. Specifically, to overcome this, he has added a short `isRStudio()` function [on package load](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/blob/ef8b1e52b80a99e96f46232dfe29180686327887/R/init.R#L49-L52) and [calls the function each time before handing data off into C++](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/blob/ef8b1e52b80a99e96f46232dfe29180686327887/R/anytime.R#L192-L206).

The [`isRStudio()` function](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/blob/ef8b1e52b80a99e96f46232dfe29180686327887/R/init.R#L53-L57) @DirkEddelbuettel uses is given as:

```
isRStudio <- if (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO", unset="0") == "1" &&
                     exists("RStudio.Version") &&
                     ## the following is evil but keeps R CMD check off our back
                     eval(parse(text=paste("RStudio.Version()$Version",
                                           ">=", "\"1.1.129\"")))) TRUE else FALSE
```

Note: The use of `eval(parse(text=...))` is to avoid running into package check issues such as...

```
.onLoad: no visible global function definition for ‘RStudio.Version’
Undefined global functions or variables:
    RStudio.Version
```

Comment: However evil, that works wonderfully. `bigKRLS` now runs fine on Windows Rstudio >= 1.1.129. I [adapted](https://github.com/rdrr1990/bigKRLS/blob/master/R/init.R) @DirkEddelbuettel's anytime solution so that unix-type users may use older versions of RStudio.  Thanks @coatless!

Comment: I would block all older RStudio version -- I had my crashes under Linux.

Comment: interesting @DirkEddelbuettel, to clarify -- did `library(bigKRLS)` crash your Linux RStudio or more general issues? Also, meant to ask, is there a reason that the anytime init.R uses `RStudio.Version()$Version` as opposed to `RStudio.Version()$version`?

Comment: I never ran bigKRLS (yet) but I would crash with package anytime on certain functions, and with package RcppMLPACK2 at package load.

Comment: OK, good thinking. I will up the threshold but my collaborator and I have (respectively) used RStudio 1.0.136 extensively on Mac and Ubuntu without issue (older too but...). Any reason to think it needs to be higher than that on the Unix side?