# R Prophet crashing Rstudio in loop

Tags: r, rcpp, rstan, facebook-prophet

I've been using prophet in R on windows for several months now and have recently started seeing random RStudio crashes. Prior to a few days ago, I was having no issues. I know that's not much to go off of, but I'm hoping someone can recognize what might be going on with my system. I've noticed that it crashes more frequently when n.changepoints is higher than the default of 25.

I see the crashes on both R 3.4 and 3.5. I have Rtools installed properly and can compile cpp code inline as documented in the [Rstan installation.](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Windows)

Here is in the system that I'm working on. I have the latest version of prophet and Rcpp.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] healthcareai_2.0.0 bindrcpp_0.2.2     odbc_1.1.6         reshape2_1.4.3     rmarkdown_1.10     prophet_0.3.0.1    Rcpp_0.12.17       lubridate_1.7.4   
 [9] dbplyr_1.2.1       forcats_0.3.0      stringr_1.3.1      dplyr_0.7.5        purrr_0.2.5        readr_1.1.1        tidyr_0.8.1        tibble_1.4.2      
[17] ggplot2_2.2.1      tidyverse_1.2.1    DBI_1.0.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-137       bit64_0.9-7        dimRed_0.1.0       httr_1.3.1         rprojroot_1.3-2    rstan_2.17.3       tools_3.5.0        backports_1.1.2   
 [9] utf8_1.1.4         R6_2.2.2           rpart_4.1-13       lazyeval_0.2.1     colorspace_1.3-2   nnet_7.3-12        withr_2.1.2        tidyselect_0.2.4  
[17] gridExtra_2.3      mnormt_1.5-5       bit_1.1-12         compiler_3.5.0     glmnet_2.0-16      cli_1.0.0          rvest_0.3.2        xml2_1.2.0        
[25] scales_0.5.0       sfsmisc_1.1-2      DEoptimR_1.0-8     psych_1.8.4        robustbase_0.93-1  digest_0.6.15      StanHeaders_2.17.2 foreign_0.8-70    
[33] pkgconfig_2.0.1    htmltools_0.3.6    rlang_0.2.1        readxl_1.1.0       ddalpha_1.3.4      MLmetrics_1.1.1    rstudioapi_0.7     bindr_0.1.1       
[41] jsonlite_1.5       ModelMetrics_1.1.0 inline_0.3.15      magrittr_1.5       Matrix_1.2-14      munsell_0.5.0      abind_1.4-5        stringi_1.1.7     
[49] yaml_2.1.19        MASS_7.3-49        plyr_1.8.4         recipes_0.1.3      grid_3.5.0         blob_1.1.1         pls_2.6-0          parallel_3.5.0    
[57] crayon_1.3.4       lattice_0.20-35    cowplot_0.9.2      haven_1.1.1        splines_3.5.0      hms_0.4.2          knitr_1.20         pillar_1.2.3      
[65] ranger_0.10.1      igraph_1.2.1       codetools_0.2-15   stats4_3.5.0       CVST_0.2-2         magic_1.5-8        glue_1.2.0         evaluate_0.10.1   
[73] data.table_1.11.4  modelr_0.1.2       foreach_1.4.4      cellranger_1.1.0   gtable_0.2.0       kernlab_0.9-26     assertthat_0.2.0   DRR_0.0.3         
[81] gower_0.1.2        prodlim_2018.04.18 broom_0.4.4        e1071_1.6-8        class_7.3-14       survival_2.41-3    geometry_0.3-6     timeDate_3043.102 
[89] RcppRoll_0.3.0     kknn_1.3.1         iterators_1.0.9    lava_1.6.1         caret_6.0-80       ipred_0.9-6
```

Here is the code that I'm running. It sometimes (1/5 times?) crashes Rstudio with a "session terminated" error.

```
for (i in 1:length(f_names)) {
  d <- data_list[[i]]

  m <- prophet(df = d, 
               holidays = h_daily,
               n.changepoints = 100,
               changepoint.prior.scale = 100)

  future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 14, freq = "day")

  f <- predict(m, future)
  forecast_list[[i]] <- f
}
```

If you've ever encountered something like this or know what I can do to give more info, please advise!

Edit: I'm using Rstudio 1.1.447. This also happens in Rgui and R command line.

Comment: Is it just an RStudio problem? Do you get the same issue if you run the code in the RGui or R command line?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of RStudio? (e.g. >= 1.1.0) There is a known issue with prior versions of RStudio having issues with boost headers. There is also a known precision issue if using [float128](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats.html) in the multiprecision library. c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247649/rcpparmadillo-bigmemory-crashes-windows-rstudio-but-no-other-gui-os-type/43248420#43248420 and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679263/using-boost-multiprecision-with-rcpp-on-windows

Comment: Happens in Rstuido 1.1.447 and Rgui as well.

Comment: Should you not point at rstan before you point at Rcpp?  The package is being used here, albeit somewhat indirectly.

Comment: Try putting `print(getLoadedDLLs())` at the end of your loop. You may be hitting the limit.

Answer (score 0):

[This was traced to a problem with rlang 0.2.1](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/592) Installing version 0.2.0 or 0.2.2 fixed the issue for me and many others. Install a specific version with `devtools::install_version("rlang", version="0.2.2")`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same when i used it to forecast on daily basis, try to do forecast on monthly basis

```
make_future_dataframe(m, periods= , freq="month")
```

For daily basis forecasting, prophet package is not working properly